# USB Not Recognized after Invalid Pull Out

Tags: linux, usb, centos-7

I have a problem, caused by me.
I just bought a NAND usb stick 2 TB which worked out of the box.

I tried to copy 36GB into it. That of course took too long so, I put my laptop on suspension to not interrupt the process, (that's what I thought). The process stopped of course, and I tried to delete half copied files. This also took too long so I closed the window and tried to delete the from command line which also took to long so I stopped the process and pulled out my usb stick.

Since then my stick is not recognized.

I can see these on journlactl

```
kernel: usb-storage 3-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
Jan 24 06:40:36 192.168.2.7 kernel: scsi host6: usb-storage 3-1:1.0
Jan 24 06:40:36 192.168.2.7 mtp-probe[29780]: checking bus 3, device 6: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-1"
Jan 24 06:40:36 192.168.2.7 mtp-probe[29780]: bus: 3, device: 6 was not an MTP device
Jan 24 06:40:36 192.168.2.7 upowerd[3864]: unhandled action 'bind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.0
Jan 24 06:40:36 192.168.2.7 upowerd[3864]: unhandled action 'bind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-1
Jan 24 06:40:37 192.168.2.7 kernel: scsi 6:0:0:0: Direct-Access     NAND     USB2DISK         0.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 4
Jan 24 06:40:37 192.168.2.7 kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
Jan 24 06:40:37 192.168.2.7 kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI removable disk
Jan 24 06:41:07 192.168.2.7 kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: Enabling HDA controller
Jan 24 06:41:13 192.168.2.7 kernel: ACPI: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.VID_: failed to evaluate _DSM
Jan 24 06:41:14 192.168.2.7 sudo[29855]:     User : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/User ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/lsusb
Jan 24 06:41:14 192.168.2.7 sudo[29855]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by User(uid=0)
Jan 24 06:41:14 192.168.2.7 sudo[29855]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Jan 24 06:45:19 192.168.2.7 kernel: brcmsmac bcma0:1: wl0: brcms_c_d11hdrs_mac80211:  txop exceeded phylen 153/256 dur 1730/150
Jan 24 06:47:02 192.168.2.7 dbus[1784]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='net.reactivated.Fprint' unit='fprintd.se
Jan 24 06:47:02 192.168.2.7 systemd[1]: Starting Fingerprint Authentication Daemon...
```

With lsusb I have this

```
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0a5c:5802 Broadcom Corp. BCM5880 Secure Applications Processor with fingerprint touch sensor
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 1bcf:2895 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 413c:8197 Dell Computer Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 045e:07fd Microsoft Corp. Nano Transceiver 1.1
Bus 003 Device 006: ID ffff:1201  
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I think

```
Bus 003 Device 006: ID ffff:1201
```

is the records for my USB.

I have Centos 7 with kernel 5.4 and xforms as window manager.

I don't know what to do.

Comment: Can you please try this device on another computer? As little of a chance as it is, I would like to rule out the computer itself. Thanks.

Comment: I have damaged a few usb drives by yanking them out in the middle of a write operation, its just a bad idea to do this. There is no fixing them afaik.

Answer (score 1):

I am sorry to inform you that the only 2TB USB flash drive available in 2020 is the [Kingston DataTraveler](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B06X1CSCZB).

All other USB flash drives indicated with this capacity are a fake product. They will usually only have a capacity of less than 128GB (or way less even), and trick the OS into thinking they have such a capacity. They will become unwritable once past their true capacity.

I highly suggest getting a refund for your purchase.

Comment: Yep, it is amazing what some people can get away with. For stuff like this, if it sounds too good to be true, it probably is...

Comment: Wait, I recall my previous statement, as it turns out it is a real product. The 2tb flash drive was released in 2017 by Kingston.

Comment: I did state this already though...xD The DataTraveler is already 3 years old...

Comment: Sorry, I skimmed it and jumped to the conclusion following that answer haha, I'll see what I can do for you...